# PHP: Manipulating existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing array $cars[]. Here's how I created the array $cars[]

```
$cars = array("1" => "Toyota", 
              "5" => "BMW",
              "7" => "Volvo",
              "32"=> "Porsche" );
```

As you can see, the indices of the array $cars[] is not in order. What I need to do is insert an array element in the array $cars[] when needed, to make it in order. I need to make the array $cars[] like this:

```
$cars = array("1" => "Toyota", 
              "2"=> "NULL",
              "3"=> "NULL",
              "4"=> "NULL",
              "5" => "BMW",
              "6"=> "NULL",
              "7" => "Volvo",
              "8"=> "NULL",
               .
               .
               .
              "31"=> "NULL",
              "32"=> "Porsche"
               .
               .
               .
              "48"=> "NULL"  );
```

A total of 48 cars. Thank you guys!

Comment: Did your teacher give you any hints?  What work have you done on this?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this-**

```
function addKeyArray(&$array)
{
    end($array);
    $max = key($array); //Get the final key as max or you can directly pass value like $max = 48; 
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        if(!isset($array[$i]))
        {
            $array[$i] = 'NULL';
        }
    }
}

addKeyArray($cars); 
ksort($cars);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($cars);
```

**Explaination:**

**addKeyArray()** will loop and check if any key miss then it will set key and after that [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) will sort array based on key.

Answer (score 0):

To insert new data into an existing array use -

```
array_push($cars, $new_value);
```

Then sort your array by using **ksort**

```
ksort($cars);
```

This will give you the array as you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array by keys try this

```
ksort($cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will help you

```
$cars = array("1" => "Toyota", 
              "5" => "BMW",
              "7" => "Volvo",
              "32"=> "Porsche" );
for($i=min(array_keys($cars));$i<=max(array_keys($cars));$i++){
    if(!isset($cars[$i])){
        $cars[$i]="NULL";
    }
}
ksort($cars);
```

If you want to start with index 1 everytime, you can change "min(array_keys($cars))" in for loop with "1"